# how to start and stop tomcat by inbuilt tomcat script files on windows?

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed tomcat 10 on windows 10 and did start and stop from command line, What is mean start and stop tomcat by inbuilt tomcat script files? How to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

export BASE="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\bin"
prog=apache-tomcat-10.0.11

stat() {
if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
echo Tomcat is running.
else
echo Tomcat is not running.
fi
}

case "$1" in
start)

if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
echo Tomcat seems to be running. Use the restart option.
else
$BASE/startup.bat 2>&1 > /dev/null
fi
stat
;;
stop)
$BASE/shutdown.bat 2>&1 > /dev/null
if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
for pid in `ps auxwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2`
do
kill -9 $pid 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
fi
stat
;;
restart)

if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
for pid in `ps auxwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2`
do
kill -9 $pid 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
fi
$BASE/startup.bat 2>&1 > /dev/null
stat
;;
status)
stat
;;
*)
echo "Usage: tomcat start|stop|restart|status"
esac
```

I got this code from internet and updated the BASE and prog variables, and saved it in bin folder of tomcat with the name StartStopScript.sh. Then through command prompt I did   bash StartStopScript.sh start command,
and I got like this

```
StartStopScript.sh: line 22: C:\Program: command not found
Tomcat is not running.
```

Kindly help me to resolve

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to run a _shell_ script in Windows. Without additional software (Cygwin, MSYS2 or similar) it is not possible. What are you trying to achieve? The script itself is rather badly written.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I got this code from internet, Actually I downloaded bash shell, and my aim is to start, stop and restart tomcat (installed on windows) by creating script file. I am new shell scripting and kindly help me @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 1):

Using scripts means using the scripts startup.bat and shutdown.bat via cmd.exe. The %CATALINA_HOME%\bin directory needs to be in PATH

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I updated my question, Can you please help me to complete. I am new to these concepts @g00se

Comment: You need to re-read the answer

Comment: Sorry I don't understand @g00se

Comment: I mentioned the names of both script files you need to concern yourself with. The one you quote is not one of them

Comment: I changed those mistakes and updated my question, Still got error Command not found, Kindly help me @g00se

Comment: Please post *as text* the content of the command you're executing in cmd.exe

Comment: I go to the corresponding location with cd command and then given bash StartStopScript.sh start  and got the error as I shown in the question @g00se

Comment: Do i *really* need to say *now for the THIRD time* that .sh files have *nothing* to do with Windows. It's the batch (.bat) files that you need